# variance of integral of Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

If $W(t)$ is a Brownian Motion and $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ non-random
functions defined as $X(t)=\int_{0}^{t}g(u)dW(u)$ and $Y(t)=\int_{0}^{t}h(u)X(u)du$.

Then we have
$$Var[Y(t)]=\int_{0}^{t}g^{2}(u)(\int_{u}^{t}h(y)dy)^{2}du.$$

My question is: how to obtain the above equation?

Any motivation or insight is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Fubini followed by Ito isometry.

Comment: Very useful comment.

Comment: Yours as well. Were you expecting that someone is doing all the work for you? $$Y_t^2 = \left( \int_0^t h(u) X(u) \, du \right) \left( \int_0^t h(v) X(v) \, dv\right)= \int_0^t \int_0^t h(u) h(v) X(u) X(v) \, du \, dv$$ What's stopping you from applying Fubini's theorem to calculate $\mathbb{E}(Y_t^2)$? (... You have an impressive accept rate for answers to your questions....)

Comment: $Var[Y(t)]=E[Y(t)^2]=E[(\int_{0}^{t}h(u)\int_{0}^{u}g(v)dW(v)du)^2]
=E[(\int_{0}^{t}\int_{u}^{t}h(u)du g(v)dW(v))^2]=\int_{0}^{t}g^{2}(u)(\int_{u}^{t}h(y)dy)^{2}du$